# "The problem is/are Jack and Jill"

Tags: verb-agreement

Which one of these sentences is correct?

> The problem **is** Jack and Jill.
>
> The problem **are** Jack and Jill.

Comment: Of the two, the first. Please note that the way your question is worded, it looks like proofreading, which is likely to be closed. To make closure less likely, you might find [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Problem* is the subject of the sentence and it is singular.
Thus, both of the following are correct:
The problem is Jack and Jill.
But:
Jack and Jill are the problem.
But not, Jack and Jill is the problem.